# Why does this for loop inside while exit before the while condition?

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop, nested, while-loop

I am reading a file and executing a while loop to iteratively run through each line in the file. Inside the while loop I have a if condition which has a nested for loop which does some processes. What happens is that the code exits once the for loop finishes despite the fact that the condition to keep the while loop running is still valid.

```
my $datafile = "data.txt";
open my $fh, "<", $datafile or die "Failed to open $datafile ($!)";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new() or die "Failed to create Text::CSV object";
my $line = <$fh>;

while ($line = <$fh>)
{ 
    blah blah
    blah blah

    if ($foo > $cow) {
        blah
    } elsif ($foo == $cow) { 
        blah
    } else {
        for ($i =1; $i <= $something; $i++) {
            blah blah
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the code is not finished going through every line of the data.txt file. The code exits once it finishes with the for loop.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the inside of the `for` loop doing?  If it reads from `<$fh>` in list context, it will consume the entire file.

Comment: You have not shown us the part of your code with the bug, so we can only guess.  Put a print statement after the for loop to see whether your program unexpectedly exited.

Comment: too much blah blah, not enough code that is actually the problem.  You might want to use the Text::CSV getline method to read your lines into the Txt::CSV object directly.  Also look into using a simple foreach or while instead of the C-style for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the debugger to see what is happening.  [perldoc perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)

Comment: Thanks Alex for the guidance. I did use the debugger and figured out what was happening. Sorry for the stupid post.